# having issues comparing strings

Tags: c++

For some reason it skips over the first input an goes straight to the second one.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int stringWork()
{
    const int LENGTH = 40;
    char firstString[LENGTH], secondString[LENGTH];
    cout << "Enter First String: ";
    //it skips over this following line
    cin.getline(firstString, LENGTH);
    cout << "Enter Another String: ";
    cin.getline(secondString, LENGTH);

    if (strcmp(firstString, secondString) == 0)
        cout << "You entered Same string two times\n";
    else
        cout << "The two strings you entered are not the same\n";
    system("pause");
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    stringWork();
    return 0;
}
```

it only allows input for one string

Comment: You should ensure you are flushing the cout buffer before you cin.getline. That might be the confusion point.

Comment: Problem? It works on my machine if change `#include <string>` to `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: Try `std::getline(std::cin, firstString)` instead.

Comment: Remove the `using namespace std;`, it is a bad habit. Second, use `std::string` instead of C style strings. You can then compare with `==`.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Great hint! Actually I didn't know this is part of `<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code works on my machine just fine. However, please do change `#include <string>` to `#include <string.h>` or `#include <cstring>`, and add `#include <stdlib.h>` or `#include <cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void stringWork()
{
    const int LENGTH = 40;
    char firstString[LENGTH], secondString[LENGTH];
    std::cout << "Enter First String: " << std::flush;
    std::cin.getline(firstString, LENGTH);
    std::cout << "Enter Another String: " << std::flush;
    std::cin.getline(secondString, LENGTH);

    if (strcmp(firstString, secondString) == 0) {
        std::cout << "You entered Same string two times." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "The two strings you entered are not the same." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stringWork();
    return 0;
}
```

Some notes about my version of your code:

- Please don't use `using namespace std`.
- Use `std::flush` to flush the characters in the output stream. This is necessary because usually the characters are only flushed with `std::endl` or in some implementations if you add a newline character.
- Avoid mixing C and C++ code as you did. Use the `std::getline` method to read a line directly into a `std::string`. Shown in the next example.
- Please care about your code style, especially if you post it in the public.

A even better implementation would avoid any C code and use just C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void stringWork()
{
    std::cout << "Enter First String: " << std::flush;
    std::string firstString;
    std::getline(std::cin, firstString);
    std::cout << "Enter Another String: " << std::flush;
    std::string secondString;
    std::getline(std::cin, secondString);

    if (firstString == secondString) {
        std::cout << "You entered Same string two times." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "The two strings you entered are not the same." << std::endl;
    }
}
```